# Why can't I download Numpy in my venv but I'ts possible outside of it?

Tags: python, windows, pip, python-packaging

I have been trying to install Numpy in my virtual environment on my windows computer using command:

```
pip -m install numpy
```

But I get a long error message that ends with the following:

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
Failed to build numpy
ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

It seems to fail after Building wheel for numpy (PEP 517).

I then tried to install numpy globally (outside of the venv) and it worked.(To my surprise)

After that I tried to download and install the C++ package in Microsoft Build Tools then I successfully downloaded and installed numpy in the venv aswell.

What I don't understand is why/how I am able to download the numpy package outside of the venv without the C++ build tool installation. Is it because I have a gcc compiler installed? Why isn't this then recognized in the venv? Why did I have to install the 7GB C++ build tool package when it was already working outside of the venv?

Comment: yes, thats because you have the GCC installed on your main system, just install it again in your env, or someone import the gcc path into the env then it should work without needing to reinstall the gcc tools from the env..

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the Python in the virtual environment is the same as "*outside*"? What is the Python version?